# javascript scope and global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this

I'm trying to avoid using global variable when using functions within objects.
I want to invoke a function inside other function and use a variable from the first function's scope.
For example:

```
var showForecast = {
  'init': function () {
    this.getData();
  },
  'buildView': function(){
    var code = "Hey, you're from " + this.data.city;
    $('body').append(code);
  },
  'getData': function () {
    $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io/', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      showForecast.buildView();
    })
  }
}
```

Clearly it's not working. I want to use `data` inside `buildView` without making `data` a global variable.
I thought using `this` would be the right course of action because I'm calling `buildView` from a function where `data` is defined.
How can this be achieved? Thanks.

Comment: @Oriol — `buildView` is called from the callback, so being asynchronous doesn't matter.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the information along:

```
var showForecast = {
'init': function () {
    this.getData();
},
'buildView': function(data){
    var code = 'Hey, you\'re from ' + data.city;
    $('body').append(code);
},
'getData': function () {
    $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io/', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        showForecast.buildView(data);
    })
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the data variable itself. That is locally scoped to the anonymous function you pass to `getJSON` (and `getJSON` passes it as an argument, which is beyond your control).

You have to copy the value somewhere.

In your particular example, there are no scopes shared between `getData` and `buildView` other than the global scope. So if you want to pass the value through scopes, then a global is your own (terrible) option.

You can simply pass it as an argument:

```
showForecast.buildView(data);
```

Or you can store it as a property:

```
showForecast.myData = data;
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Vinny's answer.

One round-bout way is to make a module out of it:

```
var showForecast = function(){
    var data;
    var init = function () {
        this.getData();
    };
    var buildView = function(){
        var code = 'Hey, you\'re from ' + this.data.city;
        $('body').append(code);
    };
    var getData = function () {
        $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io/', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            this.data = data;
            showForecast.buildView();
        })
    };
    return {
        'init': init,
        'buildView': buildView,
        'getData': getData
    };
}();
```

This way the scope of `var data` is limited to the function. It's like a private variable.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to avoid global, you should consider using namespaces. There is no such thing called namespace in Javascript. But you can define yourself using small utility method mentioned here.

http://www.zachleat.com/web/namespacing-outside-of-the-yahoo-namespace/

A utility method which helps creating custom namespaces.

```
jQuery.namespace = function() {
    var a=arguments, o=null, i, j, d;
    for (i=0; i<a.length; i=i+1) {
        d=a[i].split(".");
        o=window;
        for (j=0; j<d.length; j=j+1) {
            o[d[j]]=o[d[j]] || {};
            o=o[d[j]];
        }
    }
    return o;
};
```

Define name space

```
jQuery.namespace( 'jQuery.showForecast' );
```

Define methods using revealing module pattern

https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript

```
 jQuery.showForecast = (function() {

  var data;

  var init = function() { 
    getData();
  }

  var buildView = function() {
    var code = "Hey, you're from " + data.city;
    $('body').append(code);
  }

  var getData = function() {        
    $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io/', function(_data) {
      console.log(data);
      data = _data;
      buildView();
    })

  }

  return {
    init: init
  };

})(); // Execute it immediately
```

Usage:

You can access only init method as it is exposed to outside.

```
jQuery.showForecast.init()
```

Define another namespace

```
jQuery.namespace( 'jQuery.showForecast.extended' );

jQuery.showForecast.extended = {
// Define some more

};
```